# Fill missing dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I have dataframe contains temperature readings from different areas and in different dates

I want to add the missing dates for each location with zero temperature

for example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"area_id":[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                 "reading_date":["13/1/2017","15/1/2017"
                                 ,"16/1/2017","22/3/2017","26/3/2017"
                                 ,"28/3/2017","15/5/2017"
                                 ,"16/5/2017","18/5/2017"],
                 "temp":[12,15,22,6,14,8,30,25,33]})
```

[image]

What is the most efficient way to fill dates gap per area (by zeros) as shown below

[image: Target output]

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

- first convert to datetime column `reading_date` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)
- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `DatetimeIndex` and `groupby` with `resample`
- for `Series` add [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asfreq.html)
- replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html)
- last add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`

---

```
df['reading_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reading_date'])

df = (df.set_index('reading_date')
        .groupby('area_id')
        .resample('d')['temp']
        .asfreq()
        .fillna(0)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
    area_id reading_date  temp
0         1   2017-01-13  12.0
1         1   2017-01-14   0.0
2         1   2017-01-15  15.0
3         1   2017-01-16  22.0
4         2   2017-03-22   6.0
5         2   2017-03-23   0.0
6         2   2017-03-24   0.0
7         2   2017-03-25   0.0
8         2   2017-03-26  14.0
9         2   2017-03-27   0.0
10        2   2017-03-28   8.0
11        3   2017-05-15  30.0
12        3   2017-05-16  25.0
13        3   2017-05-17   0.0
14        3   2017-05-18  33.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `reindex`. Define a custom function to handle the reindexing operation, and call it inside `groupby.apply`.

```
def reindex(x):
    # Thanks to @jezrael for the improvement.
    return x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), x.index.max()), fill_value=0)
```

Next, convert `reading_date` to datetime first, using `pd.to_datetime`,

```
df.reading_date = pd.to_datetime(df.reading_date)
```

Now, perform a `groupby`.

```
df = (
    df.set_index('reading_date')
      .groupby('area_id')
      .temp
      .apply(reindex)
      .reset_index()
)

df.columns = ['area_id', 'reading_date', 'temp']
```

```
df

    area_id reading_date  temp
0         1   2017-01-13  12.0
1         1   2017-01-14   0.0
2         1   2017-01-15  15.0
3         1   2017-01-16  22.0
4         2   2017-03-22   6.0
5         2   2017-03-23   0.0
6         2   2017-03-24   0.0
7         2   2017-03-25   0.0
8         2   2017-03-26  14.0
9         2   2017-03-27   0.0
10        2   2017-03-28   8.0
11        3   2017-05-15  30.0
12        3   2017-05-16  25.0
13        3   2017-05-17   0.0
14        3   2017-05-18  33.0
```